# parameter is not entering in xmlhttp.open( “POST”, 'show.php', true);

Tags: javascript, php, html

my code is uploading anything what i want. what i am tring to do that when i upload the picture or file it should immediately display after selecting upload(that is in html "input name="upload" type="submit" onChange ="pict()" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload ">).Problem is that it is not entering in the page show.php through " xmlhttp.open( "POST", 'show.php', true);" . Although i did debug and failed to understand why this is not going to other page

show.php

```
<?php
echo"heloo00";
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
 mysql_select_db("project",$con) or die("error db");

$sql="select * from upload";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$image=$row ['name'];

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['content'] ) . '" />';
}
?>
```

t.html

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 #boox{
    overflow:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    }
 </style>

<script>
alert("helo");
</script>
<script>

    function pict()
    {    alert("hel");
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var picInput = document.getElementById('userfile').value;
        var uploadpic = document.getElementById('upload').value;
        document.getElementById('usf').innerHTML = picInput;
        document.getElementById('upic').innerHTML = uploadpic;  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
         alert(resp);
      } alert("a");
        xmlhttp.open( "POST", 'show.php', true); //problem
xmlhttp.send();// not happening
   }

    }    
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="take.php">
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
<tr>
<td width="246">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
</td>
<input name="upload" type="submit" onChange ="pict()" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload ">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
    </body>
     </html>
```

take.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
        {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }
         $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
         mysql_select_db("project",$con) or die("error db");

        $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
        "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
        mysql_close($con);
        echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";

        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**onChange ="pict()"**  is not getting called .
put ajax call at appropriate place ...

If you want to submit and show the image at one after another .. then use ajax to submit the image too and not a POST.

Comment: How shell i place appropiate.?? where shell i place it?

Comment: i am greatly confused ,it shell work in this way:- upload the picture -> display image immediately as happens normally when we upload picture.

Comment: as you are posting the form to upload the image  you can use the same image while your page loads again after upload.
No need to use ajax in your code sample
once you press the submit in your t.html the image will be uploaded to your server.
and a message will be displayed that image uploaded from take.php
Now go to the show.php in browser and you will get the image as you are fetching it from database